# How to delete text until the end of each line after matching a pattern in Vim?

Tags: vim, sed

I have a file with the following content:

```
domproxy1.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy10.dom.company.com Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy11.dom.company.com Centos CentOS 6.5 production  X8DTU   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy15.dom.company.com Centos CentOS 6.6 production  X8DTU   8 days ago  Edit
domproxy2.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy3.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy4.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy5.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy6.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy9.dom.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.5 production  S5520UR   7 days ago  Edit
domproxy29.dom.company.com Centos CentOS 6.6 production  S2600GZ   about 1 month ago Edit
orgcmsui03.nj.company.com  Centos CentOS 6.6 production  Virtual Mac...    6 days ago  Edit
domftp01.dom.company.com Centos CentOS 6.4 production  ProLiant DL...    40 minutes ago  Edit
```

I would like to replace the end of each line's `(.com *)` with `(.com)`, that means to delete everything after the hostname in each line.

Inside `vim`, I've tried the following:

```
:%s/.com $/.com/g
:%s/.com*$/.com/g
:%s/.com .*/.com/g
```

As far I know this is what I'm doing:

```
:%s/ - search on all the file
.com .*/ - the search pattern
.com/ - the replace pattern
/g - global
```

But to no avail, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/[.]com.*/.com
```

This will do exactly what you need.

`%s` Search entire file

`/[.]com.*` Find `.com` and whatever follows till the end of line

`/.com` Replace the searched pattern with `.com`

You don't have to use `/g` at the end as you have only one occurrence of `.com` in each line.

Use the below command if you don't want `.company.com` to be replaced with `.com`

```
:%s/[.]com\>.*/.com
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's what I needed. One day I'll understand how it all works :)

Comment: You can understand it right away! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: maybe `:%s/[.]com.*/.com` to avoid to loose `my.servercom.org`

Comment: Given there is no such as 'my.servercom.org' the given command works fine in this context. But, you are absolutely right! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: `.company.com` becomes `.com` but apparently, that's what OP wants + I have no idea why his own `%s/.com .*/.com/g` is not working for him?

Answer (score 2):

I like `:normal` for these kind of tasks:

```
:%norm f D
```

However we can do things a bit more *nix-y by using either `awk` or `cut` by filtering with `:%!`.

```
:%!cut -f1 -d' '
:%!awk '{print $1}'
:%!awk '$0=$1'
```

Substitutions using `\zs`:

```
:%s/\.com\zs.*
```

For more help see:

```
:h :normal
:h f
:h D
:h :range!
:h /\zs
:h magic
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [power of `g`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

```
:g/[.]com\>/normal nelD
```

or

```
:g/[.]com/normal nelD
```

as you desire.

It works as below:

In each line find `.com` and execute the command `nelD` in *normal* mode.

`n` find next match, `e` go to end of word, `l` move to right, `D`delete till end of line.

Comment: or even just `:%norm f d-`

Comment: Fat fingers - that should be `%norm f d$`

Comment: Save one more character. `:%norm f D`  :D

Comment: Even better :). `f ` finds the first space, not `.com` but for the examples presented by OP, that's exactly what is needed.

Comment: Understood. I deleted that comment. Didn't observe that the first space is after `.com`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
:%s/\.com\zs\s.*/
```

Match `dot 'com' whitespace` (e.g. space or tab), remove everything *after* `dot com`.

**Note**: the *dot* is escaped, otherwise *any* character matches.